# Dynamic WHERE clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a requirement to display reports if a field value or a combination of field value matches.
I have designed a table to store **ReportId** values against a field or a combination of fields. I have stored the values  in a pattern so that I can construct the WHERE clause for SQL to fetch desired data. Following is the table data:

```
 Field1 Field2 Field3 ReportId

 2       NULL   NULL  Rep1     
 5       4      NULL  Rep2
 6       NULL   8     Rep4
```

Now, I want to create a stored procedure to fetch relevant **ReportId**s. In the stored procedure I have following parameters as input:

Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3

In the stored procedure, I want to construct a SQL with a dynamic WHERE clause to fetch **ReportId**s. The WHERE clause will put a AND operator between all NON NULL fields and compare with the passed parameters.
As per the given table data, the non-null field in first row is “Field1”. So the WHERE clause will be

```
Field1 = Parameter1
```

As per the given table data, the non-null fields in the second row is “Field1” and “Field2”. So WHERE clause will be:

```
Field1 = Parameter1 AND Field2 =Parameter2
```

As per the given table data, the non-null fields in the third row is “Field1” and “Field3”. So the  WHERE clause will be:

```
Field1 = Parameter1 AND Field3 =Parameter3
```

How I can write a generic SQL with a dynamic WHERE clause for this requirement?

Comment: There's nothing dynamic needed.   If I tell you can solve your problem with a single WHERE clause that combines ()'s and AND's and OR's, can you figure it out from there?

Comment: @Tab actually in a lot of cases that can lead to reuse of the same plan that works great for some combinations but terrible for others. I talk about this in my "kitchen sink" video: http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/

Comment: Please also read http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually in the example I have given only three fields. In real case there might be more.Could you please construct the SQL?

Comment: Could anybody help to construct the SQL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand only if you don't take steps to mitigate parameter sniffing, which I always do as a matter of course, but it's getting beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @TabAlleman Also whatever you state that you do can't necessarily be assumed for every single reader ever.

Comment: Article version of Aaron's video: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/

Answer (score 3):

Le sigh.

The solution I am thinking of is a simple:

```
WHERE (Field1 IS NULL OR Field1=@Parameter1)
AND (Field2 IS NULL OR Field2=@Parameter2)
AND ...
```

You can stack any number of field/parameter pairings into this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the query by appending the where clause to NVARCHAR(MAX) variable and then execute that query with sql built in function sp_executesql

For Example

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @query = 'SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Reports WHERE 1=1 '
IF @Field1 IS NOT NULL
        SET @query = @query + 'AND Field1 = @Field1 '
......
......
......

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, 
          N'@Field1 VARCHAR(MAX),
            ....
            ....
          @Param1,
          .....
          .....
```

I hope this helps you get the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what you are looking for and restate your question it becomes easier.  What do you really want to do?  You want to include rows where each field matches the parameter passed, or whether the value in the table is null.  So you want to match rows where each field is either null, or it matches the parameter:

```
WHERE (Field1 is null OR Field1 = @Parameter1)
    AND (Field2 is null OR Field2 = @Parameter2)
    AND (Field3 is null OR Field3 = @Parameter2)
```